# JavaFX applet won't work

Tags: applet, javafx

Is anyone able to run JavaFX applets inside the web page? I am not. I also tried applet here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aim/archive/2009/07/bounds_unleashe.html (on the bottom) but it doesn't work for me. Tried on Ubuntu and Windows, on IE and Firefox. All I can see is endlessly spinning Java logo. What can be the problem?

Comment: Does your question only refer to the mentioned applet (which is, like Nosredna already said, indeed not working, due to the mising jnlp file) or do you have problems with applets in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the comments below that example, sounds like that demo doesn't work for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm
Also this link might be useful which describes the process and check an alternative which is using JavaFX in Swing applications
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_swing_apps.htm